# Ubuntu 17.10 require switch to tty7 while shudown/restart

Tags: shutdown, tty, 17.10

there is something strange in Ubuntu 17.10. When I do shutdown (or reboot) the system hangs on black empty screen with cursor only. It is not tty1, nor tty7.
The only way to let system shutdown is to switch on tty7 manually. After switching in 1-2 sec system continue shutdown itself normally. The question is how to avoid such behaviour.

Comment: I am having the same issue i need to switch to tty7 or the system won't shutdown/reboot

Comment: In my case same issue seemed to be fixed by video drivers reinstallation. Although maybe it's a coincidence and real reason was something else

Comment: I have the same problem in 17.10. In my case too switching to tty7 or sending the shutdown command from a tty console is the only way to shutdown the machine. Any update?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms.  I could get a successful reboot only by [removing `quiet splash`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968492/ubuntu-17-10-and-17-04-nvidia-quiet-splash-hangs-on-restart-or-shutdown) from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in `/etc/default/grub` (and running `sudo update-grub`).

Not a real solution, but at least it avoids the hang.

Comment: I'd try this if I had "quiet splash". I have only "splash". I'll try to remove that too.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome - Here is my fix.

I had tried everything  (10-20 different fixes, and getting frustrated - tough to troubleshoot), but this worked.

And i will re-iterate it for others.

Reduce the timeout in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`:

**Remove #** from these lines to activate them,  and change timings in these following lines  (they were 90 seconds!):

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s

DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s
```

In terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

Save, Exit (reload it to confirm the changes as i had some strange "Gedit Errors)

Then run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Reboot now in 5-10 Seconds - Awesome !

Say Thanks, Mark

Comment: ***DO NOT*** repost your same answer to many questions at once.  If questions all use the same answer and are similar enough, consider flagging the questions as duplicates of this one, rather than duplicating your answers.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work in my case. Neither 90s before editing the file system.conf, nor after setting 5s. I wait for 120s in both cases. Nothing. Only manual switching to TTY7!

Comment: Maybe someone knows how to setup systemd to do this (switch to tty7) on shutdown/reboot?