# HP dv7 - fan always on after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: 17.10, hp, fan

After the upgrade to 17.10, the fan spins up during boot and never spins down - even though the CPU usage is low and sensors report the system isn't running very hot:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +58.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +57.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:        +58.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:        +56.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  
temp2:        +58.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)
temp3:        +30.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.85 V  (min =  +0.82 V, max =  +1.12 V)
temp1:        +77.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

avn@mistral:~$ uptime
 18:41:31 up 12 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.62, 0.39, 0.23
```

Any idea what else could be making the fans run constantly?

Edit: I seem to have found a workaround while trying to fix another issue after the upgrade: the system hangs at shutdown so the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966960/ubuntu-17-10-require-switch-to-tty7-while-shudown-restart) was to remove "quiet splash" from kernel's command line.

Somehow this helped with the fans, too. I confirmed that putting these options back results in heavy fan duty again, and removing again makes the laptop quiet.

I would love to hear an explanation for this behavior. Seems like something is wrong with Plymouth?

Comment: open up a terminal and see what are the biggest resource consuming processes ...  `alt + ctrl + t`   ... then enter   `top` ... is it out of RAM  ?   that top command should give you clues

Comment: As I said, there is not much CPU activity - as evidenced by the load averages I posted. And, see the edit - it seems to be unrelated to the CPU load.

Comment: did not see load average ... I would boot up a LiveCD using the previous OS version and if its then OK  it points to 17.10 not some recent hardware fault ... if previous OS boot is OK just to be safe I would do a LiveCD book using 17.10 to isolate whether its the release or some post install change .. PS removing quite splash just eliminates showing the splash logo on boot so should not impact this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing fan-control drivers here is a fix that worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
sudo reboot
```

Comment: when I try your method, I get 

`$ sudo apt-get install fan-control
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fan-control`

Comment: It was a typing misktake package name is `fancontrol`